# Correct way to map JSON data to <Table/> by Fetch API method (react js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uitableview, fetch, fetch-api

I can't believe that I'm asking an obvious question, but I still get the error in console log.
I'm trying to map some json elements to  but can't see to figure out the correct way.
Console says that it can't recognize renderBody and BodyData.

How to render the data into Table correctly?

***Customers.js***

```
import React from 'react'

import Table from '../components/table/Table'

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

export class Customers extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            deps: [],
          };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.refershList();
    }

async refershList() {
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    await fetch('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Customers', {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${cookies.get('userToken')}` }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ deps: data });
        });
}

render() {
const { deps } = this.state;
const customerTableHead = [
    '',
    'name',
    'email',
    'phone',
    'total orders',
    'total spend',
    'location'
]

const renderHead = (item, index) => <th key={index}>{item}</th>

const renderBody = (item, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
        <td>{item.id}</td>
        <td>{item.name}</td>
        <td>{item.email}</td>
        <td>{item.phone}</td>
        <td>{item.total_orders}</td>
        <td>{item.total_spend}</td>
        <td>{item.location}</td>
    </tr>
)

const Customers = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2 className="page-header">
                customers
            </h2>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card__body">
                            <Table
                                limit='10'
                                headData={customerTableHead}
                                renderHead={(item, index) => renderHead(item, index)}
                                bodyData={deps}
                                renderBody={(item, index) => renderBody(item, index)}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Customers
```

This is the **Table.jsx** component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

import './table.css'

const Table = props => {

    const initDataShow = props.limit && props.bodyData ? props.bodyData.slice(0, Number(props.limit)) : props.bodyData

    const [dataShow, setDataShow] = useState(initDataShow)

    let pages = 1

    let range = []

    if (props.limit !== undefined) {
        let page = Math.floor(props.bodyData.length / Number(props.limit))
        pages = props.bodyData.length % Number(props.limit) === 0 ? page : page + 1
        range = [...Array(pages).keys()]
    }

    const [currPage, setCurrPage] = useState(0)

    const selectPage = page => {
        const start = Number(props.limit) * page
        const end = start + Number(props.limit)

        setDataShow(props.bodyData.slice(start, end))

        setCurrPage(page)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="table-wrapper">
                <table>
                    {
                        props.headData && props.renderHead ? (
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    {
                                        props.headData.map((item, index) => props.renderHead(item, index))
                                    }
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        ) : null
                    }
                    {
                        props.bodyData && props.renderBody ? (
                            <tbody>
                                {
                                    dataShow.map((item, index) => props.renderBody(item, index))
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        ) : null
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
            {
                pages > 1 ? (
                    <div className="table__pagination">
                        {
                            range.map((item, index) => (
                                <div key={index} className={`table__pagination-item ${currPage === index ? 'active' : ''}`} onClick={() => selectPage(index)}>
                                    {item + 1}
                                </div>
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                ) : null
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Table
```

**Table.css**

```
   .table-wrapper {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 400px;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

thead {
    background-color: var(--second-bg);
}

tr {
    text-align: left;
}

th,
td {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 15px 10px;
}

tbody > tr:hover {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--txt-white);
}

.table__pagination {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.table__pagination-item ~ .table__pagination-item {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.table__pagination-item {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.table__pagination-item.active,
.table__pagination-item.active:hover {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--txt-white);
    font-weight: 600;
}

.table__pagination-item:hover {
    color: var(--txt-white);
    background-color: var(--second-color);
}
```

API JSON data

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Brittan Rois",
      "email":"brois0@unicef.org",
      "location":"Bator",
      "phone":"+62 745 807 7685",
      "total_spend":"$557248.44",
      "total_orders":24011
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Matthew Junifer",
      "email":"mjunifer1@buzzfeed.com",
      "location":"Bromma",
      "phone":"+46 993 722 3008",
      "total_spend":"$599864.94",
      "total_orders":60195
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Finlay Baylay",
      "email":"fbaylay2@purevolume.com",
      "location":"Atalaia",
      "phone":"+55 232 355 3569",
      "total_spend":"$171337.47",
      "total_orders":96328
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "name":"Beryle Monelli",
      "email":"bmonelli3@amazonaws.com",
      "location":"Martingança",
      "phone":"+351 734 876 8127",
      "total_spend":"$335862.78",
      "total_orders":78768
   }
```

]

Answer (score 0):

I did this type of thing before functionally might wanna see mine and follow it in ur way (Note: i put searchbar and a pagination system inside the site for the tables so take into account only the required table mapping part):

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [SearchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

const [PageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);

const [Usersperpage] = useState(4);
const PagesVisited = PageNumber * Usersperpage;

const pageCount = Math.ceil(users.length / Usersperpage);

const changePage = ({ selected }) => {
    setPageNumber(selected);
}

const RenderUsers = (val) => {
    return (
        <tr key={val.id}>
            <td><Link to={`/Users/User/${val.id}`}>{val.id}</Link></td>
            <td><Link to={`/Users/User/${val.id}`}>{val.name}</Link></td>
            <td><Link to={`/Users/User/${val.id}`}>{val.email}</Link></td>
        </tr>
    )
}

const displayUsers = users.filter((val) => {
    if (SearchTerm === "") {
        return val;
    } else if (val.name.toLowerCase().includes(SearchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
        return val;
    } else if (val.email.toLowerCase().includes(SearchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
        return val;
    }
}).slice(PagesVisited, PagesVisited + Usersperpage).map(RenderUsers);


useEffect(() => {

    getUsers();

}, []);


const getUsers = async () => {

    const res4 = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    const data4 = await res4.json();
    setUsers(data4);
}


return (
    <div className="AppWhole">
        <div className="App">
            <div className="users">
                <h1 style={{ color: 'white' }}>Users</h1>

                <input type="text" className='searchUser' onChange={(e) => { setSearchTerm(e.target.value); }} />
                <div className="user">
                    <div className="app-container">
                        <ReactBootStrap.Table striped bordered hover>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        ID
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Name
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Email
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                {displayUsers}
                            </tbody>
                        </ReactBootStrap.Table>

                        <ReactPaginate
                            pageCount={pageCount}
                            onPageChange={changePage}
                            previousLabel={"<<"}
                            nextLabel={">>"}
                            containerClassName={'paginationLinks'}
                            disabledClassName={'paginationDisabled'}
                            activeClassName={'paginationActive'}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```